# running androidTest folder empty test throws errnoexception

Tags: android, testing-support-library

i have an empty android UI test for my MainActivity clas code below.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
```

public class MainActivityTest
{

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        MainActivity.class);

  @Test
  public void test()
  {

  }
}
```

its throwing an exception and I dont know why.

the log message is

"Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'android.system.ErrnoException''. Check device logcat for details
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'android.system.ErrnoException'"

I found this in the docs 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/ErrnoException.html

but It doesn't really explain much. tried googling also but with no luck.
found a few old answers on here but none using the testing support library and none of the questions had this particular type of exception. I was wondering can anyone help me out ? This may be a bit of an edge case. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your AndroidManifest.xml;
Make sure you have the defined permission below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I received the same exception, and searched on Google. I finally added this permission to resolve the problem.